# How do I get an Epson 7520 (all-in-one) printer working?

Tags: printing, epson

Can an Epson 7520 printer be installed in ubuntu 10.04LTS?

Answer (score 3):

I dont see any reason why this should not be possible.

The 7520 printer and scanner drivers are available from [Epson](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) themselves (search for 7520 and the OS of "linux")

Download the .deb files appropriate to you architecture - i386.deb for 32bit and amd64.deb for 64bit ubuntu.

Then install using the syntax:

```
sudo dpkg -i [package-filename.deb]
```

for example

```
sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.1.2-1lsb3.2_i386.deb
```